# what does 1>/dev/null 2>&1 & pid1=$! mean?

Tags: shell, parallel-processing

I am learning how to run multiple processes in parallel

```
  ./script1.sh param1 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
  pid1=$!
  ./script1.sh param2 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
  pid2=$!
```

I am not sure what is happening here:

```
   1>/dev/null 2>&1
   pid1=$!
```

Comment: Redirecting standard output to /dev/null and standard error to standard out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Redirect standard output (file handle 1) to /dev/null

```
1>/dev/null
```

Redirect standard error (file handle 2) to standard output

```
2>&1
```

Assign the PID of the most recent background command to variable pid1 (more in bash man page, [special parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters))

```
pid1=$!
```

The result is that both standard output and standard error are redirected to /dev/null

More examples can be found here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Normally three files are opened to a program: standard input, standard output and standard error. You can read more about [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) or [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) at wikipedia.

The following part of the script:

```
./script1.sh param1 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid1=$!
```

Translated to plain English:

From current directory `./` run a program `script1.sh` with parameter `param1` and redirect *standard output* to */dev/null* `1>/dev/null` and redirect *standard error* to *standard output* `2>&1`and let the program run in the background `&`. Assign the PID of the program that was just started in the background to pid1 `pid1=$!`.